# YAML syntax - lists, dictionaries

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

With the following YAML file:

- why does `policyTypes` contain a list but `metadata` doesn't?
- why does `ports` have 1 list item below it (i.e. `protocol`) whereas `port` doesn't?

I'm not interested in the Kubernetes side of things just the YAML syntax.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      role: db
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 172.17.0.0/16
        except:
        - 172.17.1.0/24
    - namespaceSelector:
        matchLabels:
          project: myproject
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          role: frontend
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
  egress:
  - to:
    - ipBlock:
        cidr: 10.0.0.0/24
    ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 5978
```

E.g. syntactically this is valid YAML:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  - name: test-network-policy
  - namespace: default
```

How is it different (from a YAML standpoint) to the first example?

Comment: You said you're not interested in k8s side of things, but this yaml is this way precisely because of the k8s side of things: this yaml is unmarshaled to a struct, and that struct has a matching format.

Comment: *„Why is this file structured that way“* Because you wrote it that way. Why did you write it that way? Because Kubernetes requires it to be that way. YAML syntax doesn't care if `policyTypes` contains a list, a mapping, a scalar, or is absent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely ignoring the Kubernetes context: YAML has sequences and mappings (exactly like JSON arrays and objects).  Everywhere you have a `-` marker it's a list item; everywhere there is a `key: value` pair it is a mapping.  You can have one inside the other.

```yaml
ports:
- protocol: TCP
  port: 6379

# is equivalent to
ports: [{"protocol": "TCP", "port": 6379}]
```

```yaml
metadata:
  name: test-network-policy
  namespace: default

# is equivalent to
metadata: {"name": "test-network-policy", "namespace": "default"}
```

```yaml
metadata:
  - name: test-network-policy
  - namespace: default

# is equivalent to
metadata: [
  {"name": "test-network-policy"},
  {"namespace": "default"}
]
```

The differences between mappings and sequences matters, and if the application expects a mapping but actually gets a sequence of mappings (compare the two `metadata:` blocks) you'll get an application-level error.

A pattern that does appear in the Kubernetes API but can be a little confusing is to have a list of objects with some logical "kind".  [Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/) within a pod spec are a good example.  These each have a key to say what kind they are, but you're allowed to have multiple volumes of the same kind, so a mapping isn't the right structure.

```yaml
volumes:
  # This is a list of mappings
  - name: logs
    emptyDir: {}
  - name: coreDumps
    emptyDir: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Why does `policyTypes` contain a list but `metadata` doesn't?

As written in [kubernetes API Reference docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.17/#networkpolicyspec-v1-networking-k8s-io) `policyTypes` field is a `string array` (in YAML data structure called a list) what means that it is a collection of values. For these particular objects only these 2 values can be specified (but standard YAML list allows to extend the values amount).

```
  policyTypes:
  - Ingress
  - Egress
```

`Metadata` is a map- it consists of key value pairs but can be further expanded by adding another map to it- for example `labels` field in `metadata` section:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: podname
  labels:
    key: value 
[...]
```

All lines must be prefixed with the same amount of spaces to belong to the same map

- why does ports have 1 list item below it (i.e. protocol) whereas port
  doesn't?

Similar as before- `ports` field is a `map inside list` and for `NetworkPolicy` object only `port` and `protocol` can be specified. Definition of `port` field:

> The `port` on the given protocol. This can either be a numerical or named port on a pod. If this field is not provided, this matches all port names and numbers.

So it is `key: value` pair, same as `protocol` field.